# PHP regex to find links

Tags: php, regex

So im currently working on a regex that's gonna be used on a forum that also had bbcode support. This regex is suppose to catch all link's beginning with https,http and www and make them to links.

Currently it catches all https and http but not the www ones. And i can't figure out how to fetch the ones that starts with www.

Also have in mind, if the link is already inside a bbcode it should not be catched in this regex.

```
return preg_replace('/(?<!src=[\"\'])(http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?[\/a-zA-Z0-9%\?\.\-]*)(?=$|<|\s)/','<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Comment: A link always has a protocol leading scheme. You are trying to interpret some string that _might_ be interpreted as a reference, that is a risky thing. Also only few host names of web servers still carry the traditional `www.` prefix used in the 1980th...

Comment: The www support is because users on current version of the site are not copying & pasting urls from the site. Instead they know the address and add www. instead of http:// in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest trying:

```
(?<!src=[\"\'])((http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?|(www\.))[\/a-zA-Z0-9%\?\.\-]*)(?=$|<|\s)
```

I believe this should catch the http(s) and www.